# IntelliJ IDEA Terminal brings his own colors from System?

Tags: colors, intellij-idea, terminal, ide, console

I configure my IDE to use the installed Git-Bash. Unfortunately both Terminals (Default the Windows CMD and the git-bash sh.exe) have that blue line-background-color.
I've already changed the colors in the system native terminal windows.
Also I tried to change the colors under (IntelliJ) Settings --> IDE Settings --> Editors --> Color & Fonts --> Console Colors.
Nothing was working

Anybody have an idea?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably happened because you had customised your cmd.exe default colors. Resetting them back to default white text on black background fixed it for me under Idea too.

For immediate effect, you can try using `color 07` command in terminal to set it to white text on black.

Comment: I understood that the default settings of "cmd" were used in the intellij environment. So we have to modify them so that it can be repeated in the Intellij terminal. to do this, open cmd, right click => default parameter and change the color parameters.

Answer (score 3):

None of the other answers quite worked for me.

What did work is this:

(in Settings -> Tools -> Terminal -> Shell path)

```
"cmd.exe" /k color 07
```

Answer (score 1):

For me resetting cmd-prompt to default colors did not work in IntelliJ 15. It still had the old cmd-prompt colors from the time when I installed IntelliJ.

In this case you can go to **File -> Settings -> Tools -> Terminal** and enter "*cmd.exe /T:07*" as **Shell path** option. This will start the terminal and reset the color to default black background and white font.

BTW: This way you can keep your favorite color settings in cmd-prompt.

Comment: This is the best solution for me (I didn't want to mess up my console colors) but I had to put the cmd.exe part into quotation marks, like this `"cmd.exe" /T:07`. Without it, i get the error 'java.io.Exception: Couldn't create PTY'

Answer (score 0):

You can set the global selection color at: IDE Settings -> Editor -> Color & Fonts -> General -> Selection Background. It also applies for the terminal, I've just tried it.

Comment: No that won't help at all. You are right: Normally this would change the colors of the terminal indeed, but in this case It seems like it has no effect. I guess this behavior is also "controlled" by the OS.

I also testet it in intelliJ on Mac OS X but everything looks correct.